# Activeadmin Custom Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've got a resource `Team` which `:has_many Users`.

I'd like to be able to display a list of teams with the team size (`team.users.count`), and make team size sortable.

Obviously this requires a `JOIN/COUNT`, what's the best way of achieving this?

Many thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

try this for descending order and use asc for ascending.

```
Team.joins(:users).group("user.team_id").order("count(user.team_id) desc")
```

***Original Answer Below***

I'm not sure what the context is but I'd do something like this in html.erb:

```
<% @whatever_teams_belong_to.teams.each do |team| %>
<%= team.name %>
<%= team.users.count %>
<% end %>
```

No Joins necessary.

Comment: crap just saw the sortable thing, sorry for the lousy answer.

Comment: I'll see if I can make it work with sortable later and get back to you! Thanks for answering!